# docker compose up raises ModuleNotFound

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, fastapi

Trying to bring my fastAPI app together with docker compose. It works out of the docker but on docker it doesn't see my modules like endpoints and others. Not sure what Am doing wrong...

```
from endpoints import pizza_endpoints, order_endpoints
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'endpoints'
```

endpoints is folder with **init** and its imports are .py files

dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9-slim

COPY ./backend /backend

ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/backend"
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /backend

EXPOSE 8000

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

docker compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  backend:
    build: .
    command: bash -c 'while !</dev/tcp/db/5432; do sleep 1; done; uvicorn backend.main:app --host 0.0.0.0'
    ports:
      - 8008:8000
    environment:
      - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@db:5432/pypizza
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:13-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=pypizza

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

main.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from endpoints import pizza_endpoints, order_endpoints
from dependency import database
from SQL import models

models.Base.metadata.create_all(database.engine)

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins = ["*"],
    allow_credentials = True,
    allow_methods = ["*"],
    allow_headers = ["*"]
)
app.include_router(pizza_endpoints.router, prefix="/pizza")
app.include_router(order_endpoints.router, prefix="/order")


@app.get("/")
async def welcome_page():
    return {"message": "hello"}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug if the filesystem is correct inside the container?

Comment: Why this is happening depends on the file structure of your project

Comment: This app works if not used in docker. Structure has been tested. Seems like docker does not recognize folder as python module despite init file exists.